# Openshift inter-pods communication

Tags: openshift, communication

I am working in an openshift environment containing multiple services. I want to call one service (say service **B**) from within another service (say service **A**). Is it possible to communicate between the services using **http**, and **not https**? I am asking this because when using **https** I get into some certificate problems (I am using Java).

I tried using service-name.namespace:port and I can reach service **B** from the pod of service **A**. But what I am doing is an **https** call. With **http** doesn't work.

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Does your service actually listen on multiple ports, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS? As you are contacting the service direct and not going via OpenShift router layer, will all depend on what your service is doing and what it is listening on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inter process communication will be done over http since the service is just a tcp proxy which load balances to the Pods running behind it.

In Pod B, try do a `dig <service>.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local`, you should see that resolve, then try `curl http://<service>.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local:port`